# Query all items with primary key in a given range and secondary key matching a given value

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamoDB table that stores sentences. Each sentence has a primary key called 'id' (of type int) and other secondary keys for each word in the sentence.

For example, the entry "hello world" would have some integer as id and would have entries "hello"=1 and "world"=1. I need to query all sentences that have id within a given range and that contain a word from a list of given words (words = [word1, word2, word3, word4, word5]). The query I have so far is:

```py
while items == []:
      response = lyric_table.scan(
                          FilterExpression=(Key(words[0]).eq(1) | 
                                            Key(words[1]).eq(1) | 
                                            Key(words[2]).eq(1) | 
                                            Key(words[3]).eq(1)| 
                                            Key(words[4]).eq(1)) & 
                                            filt,
                          ExclusiveStartKey={'id': r},)
      items = response['Items']
```

where

```py
filt = Key('id').between(r1, r2) | Key('id').between(r3, r4) ...
```

I am also selecting the ExclusiveStartKey to be a random number chosen from r1, r3, ... in each iteration of the while loop, although I am not sure if this is necessary.

This code is working as expected when "words" contain words that are relatively common in the table, but is taking too much time to run for when "words" contains words that are not too common in the database. In some cases, the scan just runs indefinitely. I also tried using query instead of scan, but had no luck in improving the code with that.

Do you have any suggestions on how to optimize the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to efficiently carry out a range operation in Dynamodb is if the attribute is a sort key(or secondary key) on a table or index. If its a partition key(or primary key), Dynamodb hashes it to distribute randomly. This is by design to allow for read/write scalability. Range operation on the partition key will involve a table scan and so, it won’t be efficient.

If I understand your question correctly, your data looks something like this:

`Id    Word    SomeValue
101    Hello    1
101    World    2`

If you know the complete range of your ids (say, 1-1000), one solution may be to bucket these ids, use the bucket key as the partition key and Id as the sort key:

`BucketId    Id
1        ..
1        ..
100        101
100        101
100        121
…
200
300
:
1000`

And then for a range of (101, 320), you can do 3 queries on ids 100, 200 and 300 with the appropriate filter expressions. This will definitely be much more efficient than a table scan. As for words, not sure what your particular use case is, but if they are limited in number per id, they can be stored as a single map or set attribute.